# Is there a Joomla 3.x content edit workflow plugin?

Tags: joomla, workflow

I was wondering if something possible as a workflow plugin was available.

When i mean workflow, i mean, a front-end management user would edit an article, and this would trigger an approval request, and the edit wouldn't go live until the approval was accepted. Something such as a backoffice would be available on maybe only an email or something that an administrator would need to accept before the change go live.

I have seen countless plugins for Prearticle management where before publishing it there is a workflow. But this is not what i am looking, i am looking for the same process but for when the article is already published, when a change is done to that article.

Is there such a thing for Joomla 3.x available i have searched alot and came to nothing, so i am asking help from the community.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: there two scenarios 1. user creating a new article  : at this time some script will work which will make the created article un-publish and then sends a mail to admin. 2 user is updating an article : in this case the article also gets un-published and mail will be generated to admin. The updated article will not be visible to the users untill it will be approved by the admin.

Comment: If all you need is a notification that there is a new article, that's built in already.  First, using the default ACL groups, an "author" dos not have a the right to pubish.  Users who have the  get a message every time a new item is created.  This message uses the internal messaging system. Each user with access to that system (only people with access to the administrator) can set their notifications to generate an email or not. By default the email is sent.

Answer (score 0):

Things like this can help?

> http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/extension-specific/extensions-specific-non-sorted/workflow-for-simple-content-versioning

Features of the tool in the above link include:

- Revise, edit and approve article changes before going live with those changes.
- Send article changes for approval via email
- Edit and save changes to published articles without affecting the live site
- Save notes regarding article versions
- Optionally stage all content changes automatically
- Automatically stage content from specific user groups
- Optional administrator email notifications of staged content that is ready for review
- Complete revision history with access to all staged and prior versions of article content
- Optionally disable on the front-end

The following is yet another tool, but too powerful a tool for your requirement, still you may want to have a look at it.

> http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/clients-a-communities/communities/community-builder